# Popover doesn't appear from directive added to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to create a directive for the Bootstrap Popover feature.

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('firstApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.directive('popover', function() {
   return function(scope, elem) {
      console.log(elem)
      elem.popover({trigger: 'hover','placement': 'left'});
   }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class='content' ng-repeat ='item in items'>
     <button type="button" popover class="testBtn btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Vivamus sagittis." title='what?'>
        Popover on left
     </button>
 </div>
```

I don't see the log in my console and the popover feature doesn't work as expected.

Comment: suggest creating a demo in plunker. Should probably remove the data attributes that bootstrap.js uses to auto initialize with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the proper attributes on the element for UI Bootstrap Popover:

It should instead look like something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="testBtn btn btn-default" popover="Vivamus sagittis."
popover-trigger="click" popover-title='what?' popover-placement='left'>
   Popover on left
</button>
```

.. and you don't need to define your own directive as you've shown.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/77qLKM4PK2L2KuePXJ5l?p=preview)

[UI Bootstrap Docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

If instead you're looking to create your own directive (ie. not using UI Bootstrap), you need to add some significant pieces to what you've shown in your code. I assume that you actually *aren't* looking to do so based on the fact that you've injected 'ui.bootstrap' into your app, but, in any case, here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PsIVSXreL12sqbRxXiI7?p=preview) showing how that might work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some aspects of defining a directive. Try something like this to get a **flexible** popover:

```
app.directive('popover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;

            el.popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But using 'ui.bootstrap' you should already have all this without needing to redefine this directive.

If the module is added correctly you should get your popover just by adding this:

```
popover-placement="left" popover="On the Top!"
```

Comment: you can create a directive that only returns a function which is same as "link" property. Also no need to wrap `el` in `$()` as it is already a jQlite or jQuery object( if jQuery loaded before angular)